# Get "@" items in atom structure

Tags: json, xml-parsing, atom-feed

I'm trying to traverse an atom tree to get to a specific item value:

```
[
  {"@":{"rel":"mentioned",
        "ostatus:object-type":"http://activitystrea.ms/schema/1.0/collection",
        "href":"http://activityschema.org/collection/public"}},
  {"@":{"rel":"enclosure",
        "type":"image/jpeg",
        "length":"225009",
        "href":"https://framapiaf.org/system/media_attachments/files/000/701/279/original/19ed3ec381293bd8.jpg"}},
  {"@":{"rel":"enclosure",
        "type":"image/jpeg",
        "length":"180205",
        "href":"https://framapiaf.org/system/media_attachments/files/000/701/280/original/101ec4084b0b1920.jpeg"}},
  {"@":{"rel":"enclosure",
        "type":"image/jpeg",
        "length":"257325",
        "href":"https://framapiaf.org/system/media_attachments/files/000/701/281/original/dff3d3dc2e8e1b89.jpg"}},
  {"@":{"rel":"enclosure",
        "type":"image/jpeg",
        "length":"224565",
        "href":"https://framapiaf.org/system/media_attachments/files/000/701/282/original/983f3ad336ebc721.jpg"}},
  {"@":{"rel":"alternate",
        "type":"text/html",
        "href":"https://mastodon.art/@luka/99809176628976105"}}
]
```

(This is the output of `JSON.stringify(item['activity:object'].link)`)

But I can't seem to get past those "`@`" keys ; How can I access the first `@.type` and `@.href`?

Comment: Looks like you're using some sort of javascript... you have an array... index one of the objects and access the properties you're expecting... `result[1]['@'].type`

Comment: @JeffMercado that actually works ; thanks!